# how to reinstall a removed package

Tags: synaptic, reinstall

I removed `oem-video-fglrx-pinglin` package in synaptic manager when starting to install wine. I changed my mind and was able to reinstall the other packages but not the above. The package is no longer appearing in synaptic manager repository. I'm not great using terminal but tried typing

```
sudo apt-get oem-video-fglrx-pinglin
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The package isn't a package from the Ubuntu repositories. It's an Original Equipment Manufacturer (OEM) package.

First try the correct syntax to install a package:

```
sudo apt-get install oem-video-fglrx-pinglin
```

If this doesn't work, than either you have luck and you can find the deb file in `/var/cache/apt/archives` via:

```
find /var/cache/apt/archives -type f -iname 'oem-video-fglrx-pinglin*'
```

and you can install it via:

```
sudo find /var/cache/apt/archives -type f -iname 'oem-video-fglrx-pinglin*' -exec dpkg -i {} \;
```

or
you have a CD/DVD or a backup with this package.

If not, the last option is: Ask your manufacturer or your dealer or visit the download area of their website.

Comment: none of the command lines  worked so will try your last suggestion if that is the only option left.

Comment: I do have the back up of the ubuntu installation made when first installing - could I download it from there?

Comment: Yes, if you can access to the backup.

Comment: I had a look, the file is probably there on the back up but it is way beyond me to understand how to extract it without reinstalling ubuntu.

Comment: If you can see the deb file, the installation is simple.

Comment: I can't find exact file but have found 'oem-browser-defaults/oem-browser-defaults_11stella3_all.deb' package on my back-up. Should I try opening this up in Software Centre or Gdebi package installer or would that just create more problems?

Comment: No, that sounds like default settings for some browser.